# Could not open ServletContext resource

Tags: java, spring, glassfish, web.xml

This is quite similar question to one older but the solution did not work for me.

I have a WAR package.

In `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

In `application-context.xml`

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:social.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But getting this:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/social.properties]

I checked the WAR package - `.xml` and `.properties` files are both in `/WEB-INF/classes`

`.properties` file is in `src/main/resources` and `.xml` in `src/main/java` (in default package both) and maven transports them (I think) correctly in the default package of `WEB-INF/classes`

Does anyone know why i could get this exception? Thank you.

EDIT: I just want to add that JUnit tests goes correctly (i mean they load what they should from `social.properties`) but when running the app it ignores my `classpath:` prefix

Comment: Are you sure that `classpath:` prefix is actually there?

Comment: yes, after build it tells me `/home/...-DEVELOPMENT-0.0.1.war` build successful. When I open the war and look at `/WEB-INF/classes/application-context.xml` i see the `classpath:` prefix

Comment: you say ".xml and .properties files are both in /WEB-INF/classes" - does that mean that "social.properties" specifically is in /WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: yes social.properties (and also log4j.properties - but it does not matter) and also application-context.xml are in /WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Doesn't application-context.xml go in `/WEB-INF` and not `/WEB-INF/classes`?

Comment: @Michael no it should go in `classes`

Comment: it can go wherever you tell it to. By default it's in /WEB-INF

Comment: I just uploaded the minimized (deleted libs) war package on my university webpage [link]http://fi.muni.cz/~xkunc7/develop.war if it could help to anyone (i mean me :-) )

Comment: Maybe you need a forward slash to say that the properties file is located at the root of the classpath? `classpath:/social.properties`

Comment: Pom is in the `develop.war` also. Look at `META-INF`.

Comment: What is the log output when you set the log level to debug?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Do not use classpath. This may cause problems with different ClassLoaders (container vs. application). WEB-INF is always the better choice.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
     <property name="location">
         <value>/WEB-INF/social.properties</value>
     </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: How can we use `BufferedWriter` for a file loaded in this manner?

Comment: @user75782131 you could try `getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/somefile.txt")`

Comment: for the above since the file are inside classes should be use <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/spring-config.xml</param-value>

Answer (score 18):

Put the things like `/src/main/resources/foo/bar.properties` and then reference them as `classpath:/foo/bar.properties`.

Comment: I've a json file path in properties.

Answer (score 8):

Try to use `classpath*:` prefix instead.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-classpath-wildcards

Also please try to deploy exploded war, to ensure that all files are there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

My filename was `jpaContext.xml` and it was placed in `src/main/resources`. I specified param `value="classpath:/jpaContext.xml"`.

Finally I renamed the file to `applicationContext.xml` and moved it to the WEB-INF directory and changed param value to `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`, then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think currently the application-context.xml file is into src/main/resources AND the social.properties file is into src/main/java... so when you package (mvn package) or when you run tomcat (mvn tomcat:run) your social.properties disappeared (I know you said when you checked into the .war the files are here... but your exception says the opposite).

The solution is simply to put all your configuration files (application-context.xml and social.properties) into src/main/resources to follow the maven standard structure.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having Tomcat unpack the WAR file?  It seems that the files cannot be found on the classpath when a WAR file is loaded and it is **not** being unpacked.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code...

```
 <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
         <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
             <property name="locations">
              <list>                        
                    <value>/social.properties</value>               
              </list>
         </property>         
        </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark sure propertie file is in "/WEB-INF/classes" try to use

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>/WEB-INF/classes/social.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```