# Error: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey with Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I have a simple two table application written in Spring MVC and which uses Hibernate. Everything works perfectly well but if I try to unit test one of the controllers, I get message:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
```

The unit test method is below:

```
@RunWith(value=SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("file:C:/NetBeansProjects/Library/build/web/WEB-INF/library- servlet.xml")
public class TestPersonController {

@Autowired
private PersonService personService;
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
}

@Test
public void testGetProfile() {
    Person mockPerson = new Person();
    mockPerson.setPersonId(1);
    mockPerson.setName("Mr Brown");
    mockPerson.setAddress("Utopia Planitia on Mars");
    mockPerson.setTelephone("1234567890"); 
    mockPerson.setEmail("brown@brown.com");

    when(personService.get(1)).thenReturn(mockPerson);
    try {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/person/profile?personId=1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("view/profile"))
            .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/view/profile.jsp"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("person", hasSize(1)))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("person", hasItem(
                    allOf(
                            hasProperty("personId", is(1)),
                            hasProperty("name", is("Mr Brown")),
                            hasProperty("address", is("53 Onslow Gardens")),
                            hasProperty("telephone", is("1234567890")),
                            hasProperty("email", is("brown@brown.com"))
                    )
            )));

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Misc.printStackTrace(e);
    }
    verify(personService, times(1)).get(1);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(personService);        
}
```

}

The two classes forming the model of the application are joined via a 1:M relationship. The first table Person has:

```
@Id
@Column(name="PERSON_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)    
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer personId;

@Column(name="NAME", nullable=false, length=50)      
private String name;

@Column(name="ADDRESS", nullable=false, length=100)
private String address;

@Column(name="TELEPHONE", nullable=false, length=10)
private String telephone;

@Column(name="EMAIL", nullable=false, length=50)
private String email;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="person") 
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Book> books;
```

And the second table has:

```
@Id
@Column(name="BOOK_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer bookId;

@Column(name="AUTHOR", nullable=false, length=50)
private String author;

@Column(name="TITLE", nullable=false, length=50)
private String title;

@Column(name="DESCRIPTION", nullable=false, length=500)
private String description;        
@Column(name="ONLOAN", nullable=false)
private boolean onLoan;


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="person_id")
@JsonBackReference
private Person person;
```

These classes work correctly under all other circumstances except this new unit test of a method in the Person controller.

I do not use the @ForeignKey annotation in my classes because there seems to be no need to and if I try, Java says it is unnecessary.

Do I have a dependency issue or what?

The unit test stacktrace follows:

```
Testsuite: library.person.TestPersonController
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.085 sec

------------- Standard Error -----------------
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
------------- ---------------- ---------------
Testcase: testGetProfile(library.person.TestPersonController):  Caused an ERROR
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:155)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private library.service.PersonService library.controller.admin.AdminController.personService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private library.dao.PersonDAOImpl library.service.PersonService.personDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory library.dao.PersonDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [file:C:/NetBeansProjects/Library/build/web/WEB-INF/library-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:129)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private library.service.PersonService library.controller.admin.AdminController.personService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private library.dao.PersonDAOImpl library.service.PersonService.personDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory library.dao.PersonDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [file:C:/NetBeansProjects/Library/build/web/WEB-INF/library-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private library.dao.PersonDAOImpl library.service.PersonService.personDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory library.dao.PersonDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [file:C:/NetBeansProjects/Library/build/web/WEB-INF/library-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private library.dao.PersonDAOImpl library.service.PersonService.personDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory library.dao.PersonDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [file:C:/NetBeansProjects/Library/build/web/WEB-INF/library-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory library.dao.PersonDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [file:C:/NetBeansProjects/Library/build/web/WEB-INF/library-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory library.dao.PersonDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [file:C:/NetBeansProjects/Library/build/web/WEB-INF/library-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [file:C:/NetBeansProjects/Library/build/web/WEB-INF/library-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2881)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1795)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)


Test library.person.TestPersonController FAILED
```

Props file config:

```
<!-- Spring Properties file for Library. -->         
    <bean id="propertiesFactory" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location">
           <value>/WEB-INF/library.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Seems you have a conflict of versions, what ORM **version** mechanism you are using?

Comment: I'm using Hibernate 4 with Spring 4, but everything with it seems to work happily.

Comment: Could you post the complete error stack trace? I want see more details, specially what line throws the exception.

Comment: It has been added to the question.

Comment: this same error get in WebLogic how to this /

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`JoinColumn.foreignKey()` was introduced with JPA 2.1, which was not implemented by Hibernate 4 until version 4.3. If you're using an older version of Hibernate 4 then try upgrading to 4.3.x.

If you're already using Hibernate 4.3 then make sure you're also using JPA 2.1 to make sure the API and implementation match up.

Comment: I am using `Hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar`, `hibernate-4.3.5.Final.jar` and `javax.persistence_2.0.0.jar`. These seem to match what you're saying.

Comment: Ah, [javax.persistence_2.0.0.jar](http://grepcode.com/file/maven.glassfish.org/content/repositories/eclipselink/org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence/2.0.0/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.java?av=f) does not contain `JoinColumn.foreignKey()`. Try removing or upgrading that dependency.

Comment: Unfortunately, even the new version of `javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar` gives the same result.

Comment: You may have to clean your project depending on how it's built to make sure the references to the 2.0.0 version get completely removed.

Comment: That appears to have helped. But for some reason now I'm getting message `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/library.properties]` when I try to run the test class. The properties file is where it should be though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's an unrelated problem. Check out [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035464/could-not-open-servletcontext-resource).

Comment: As I said though, the props file is where it should be because the application uses it. Its config has been added to the question. The config matches the other incident reported.

Comment: You should still consider researching this problem as new and potentially asking a new SO question since it does not seem obvious that Spring not loading a property file has anything to do with your original Hibernate/JPA question.

Comment: I will be investigating it quite soon. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good catch on the JPA API jar !

Answer (score 17):

**If you are on JBoss EAP 6.4.x**

Chances are it came with the JPA 2.0 and you will need to manually update it to 2.1! Follow the simple steps which worked for me.

**Download the JPA 2.1 from maven repository and update the JBoss module**
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api

**Copy the file into the JBoss modules directory**
[image]

**Update the module.xml on the same directory**
[image]

Comment: I'm dealing with JBoss deployments now and this REALLY helped me!  Thanks!

Comment: Same here, saved me a great deal of time! Thanks!

Comment: That was the problem in my case. Thank you very much, and have a happy Easter!

Comment: had same problem upgraded my hibernate jpa version from 2.0 to 2.1 and it worked like charm.

Comment: This comment helped me solved my issue. Using gradle, I originally only had `implementation 'org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate4:3.6'` in `dependencies` block in build.gradle, which pulled in hibernate-jpa-2.0 automatically, causing issue described in original post above.  I solved it by:
`dependencies {
    implementation 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.2.Final' 
    implementation 'org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate4:3.6'
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround can be found here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-209

**workaround 1**
update the javaee/api/main.module.xml as followed:

```
<!--<module name="javax.persistence.api" export="true"/>-->
<module name="javax.persistence.api" export="false"/>
```

though this is non-portable.

**workaround 2**

update jboss-deployment-structure.xml as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jpa" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- WFCORE-209 workaround -->
            <module name="javaee.api" />
            <!-- --------------------- -->
            <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
            <module name="org.hibernate" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- WFCORE-209 workaround -->
            <module name="javax.activation.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.annotation.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.ejb.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.el.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.enterprise.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.enterprise.deploy.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.inject.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.interceptor.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.jms.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.jws.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.mail.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.management.j2ee.api" export="true"/>
            <!-- <module name="javax.persistence.api" export="true"/> -->
            <module name="javax.resource.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.rmi.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.security.auth.message.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.security.jacc.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.servlet.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.transaction.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.validation.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" export="true"  services="export"/>
            <module name="javax.xml.bind.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.xml.registry.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.xml.soap.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.xml.ws.api" export="true"/>

            <!-- This one always goes last. -->
            <module name="javax.api" export="true"/>
            <!-- --------------------- -->
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

this is fully portable

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this similar problem, there was an old version(hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0-Final.jar) in my lib folder which I guess has been preventing maven dependency from loading.

So after I manually deleted it and added (hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0-Final.jar) everything started to work.