# Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in Hibernate 4.3.5.final core

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss

There was a similar question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588860/error-javax-persistence-joincolumn-foreignkeyljavax-persistence-foreignkey-wi) but I'm not using Spring and JPA. Also, I've already tried the solution and don't have success. The Hibernate version is different too.

Problem:
An **EAR project** with **EJB 3.1** , **Hibernate 4.3.5.Final** no JPA, using **Hibernate Core (Mysql)**.

The deployed project is up, with no errors in deploy.

After I created two Entity's using `@ManytoOne` mapping, I'm getting the error:

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2881)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1795)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788)
```

(The error was too long, if want the stackTrace, please tell.)

Here are the two Entity's I created, and then, the error appeared:

```
        package br.gov.xyz.malotes.model;

        import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
        import javax.persistence.Column;
        import javax.persistence.Entity;
        import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
        import javax.persistence.Id;
        import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
        import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

        import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

        @Entity
        public class Usuario {
            @Id
            @GenericGenerator(name="gen",strategy="increment")
            @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
            @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
            private int id;

            private String nome;

            private String login;

            private String senha;

            @ManyToOne//(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  // TIRAR A CASCATA AQUI AGRANTE QUE A TABELA UNIDADE NAO SEJA ALTERADA SEM QUERER
            @JoinColumn(name="unidade_id")
            private Unidade unidade;


            public Unidade getUnidade() {
                return unidade;
            }
            public void setUnidade(Unidade unidade) {
                this.unidade = unidade;
            }
            public int getId() {
                return id;
            }
            public void setId(int id) {
                this.id = id;
            }
            public String getNome() {
                return nome;
            }
            public void setNome(String nome) {
                this.nome = nome;
            }
            public String getLogin() {
                return login;
            }
            public void setLogin(String login) {
                this.login = login;
            }
            public String getSenha() {
                return senha;
            }
            public void setSenha(String senha) {
                this.senha = senha;
            }



        }
```

The other entity:

```
        package br.gov.xyz.malotes.model;

        import java.util.Set;

        import javax.persistence.Column;
        import javax.persistence.Entity;
        import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
        import javax.persistence.Id;
        import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
        import javax.persistence.Table;

        import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

        @Entity
        public class Unidade {

            @Id
            @GenericGenerator(name="gen",strategy="increment")
            @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
            @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
            private int id;

            @OneToMany(mappedBy="unidade")
            private Set<Usuario> usuario;

            private String nome;

            private String endereco;

            public Set<Usuario> getUsuario() {
                return usuario;
            }

            public void setUsuario(Set<Usuario> usuario) {
                this.usuario = usuario;
            }

            public void setId(int id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public String getNome() {
                return nome;
            }

            public void setNome(String nome) {
                this.nome = nome;
            }

            public String getEndereco() {
                return endereco;
            }

            public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
                this.endereco = endereco;
            }



        }
```

If necessary, here is the **pom.xml** in Maven:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
                   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

               <parent>
                  <artifactId>malotes</artifactId>
                  <groupId>br.gov.xyz</groupId>
                  <version>0.1</version>
               </parent>

               <artifactId>malotes-ejb</artifactId>
               <packaging>ejb</packaging>

               <name>malotes EJB module</name>

               <dependencies>

               <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
            </dependency>

                  <!-- Declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All of 
                 them are provided by JBoss AS 7 -->

                  <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
                 in JBoss AS 7 -->
                  <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
                 <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
                 <scope>provided</scope>
                  </dependency>

                  <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
                 in JBoss AS 7 -->
                  <dependency>
                 <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
                 <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
                 <scope>provided</scope>
                  </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.6</version>
            </dependency>



                  <!-- Test scope dependencies -->
                  <dependency>
                 <groupId>junit</groupId>
                 <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                  </dependency>

                  <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
                  <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and 
                 Transactional(JTA) JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->


               </dependencies>



               <build>
                  <plugins>
                 <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                       <!-- Tell Maven we are using EJB 3.1 -->
                       <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                    </configuration>
                 </plugin>


                 <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <source>1.7</source>
                      <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                  <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <source>1.7</source>
                      <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                  <source>1.7</source>
                  <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
                  </plugin>



                  </plugins>
               </build>

               <profiles>
                  <profile>
                 <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it 
                    to run just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
                 <!-- Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including 
                    Arquillian tests that execute in the specified container -->
                 <id>default</id>
                 <activation>
                    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                 </activation>
                 <build>
                    <plugins>
                       <plugin>
                      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                      <version>2.4.3</version>
                      <configuration>
                         <skip>true</skip>
                      </configuration>
                       </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                 </build>
                  </profile>

                  <profile>
                 <!-- We add the JBoss repository as we need the JBoss AS connectors 
                    for Arquillian -->
                 <repositories>
                    <!-- The JBoss Community public repository is a composite repository 
                       of several major repositories -->
                    <!-- see http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users -->
                    <repository>
                       <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
                       <name>JBoss Repository</name>
                       <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                       <!-- These optional flags are designed to speed up your builds 
                      by reducing remote server calls -->
                       <releases>
                       </releases>
                       <snapshots>
                      <enabled>false</enabled>
                       </snapshots>
                    </repository>
                 </repositories>

                 <pluginRepositories>
                    <pluginRepository>
                       <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
                       <name>JBoss Repository</name>
                       <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                       <releases>
                       </releases>
                       <snapshots>
                      <enabled>false</enabled>
                       </snapshots>
                    </pluginRepository>
                 </pluginRepositories>

                 <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests 
                    in your JBoss AS instance -->
                 <!-- This profile will start a new JBoss AS instance, and execute 
                    the test, shutting it down when done -->
                 <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-managed -->
                 <id>arq-jbossas-managed</id>
                 <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                       <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                       <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
                       <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                 </dependencies>
                  </profile>

                  <profile>
                 <!-- We add the JBoss repository as we need the JBoss AS connectors 
                    for Arquillian -->
                 <repositories>
                    <!-- The JBoss Community public repository is a composite repository 
                       of several major repositories -->
                    <!-- see http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users -->
                    <repository>
                       <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
                       <name>JBoss Repository</name>
                       <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                       <!-- These optional flags are designed to speed up your builds 
                      by reducing remote server calls -->
                       <releases>
                       </releases>
                       <snapshots>
                      <enabled>false</enabled>
                       </snapshots>
                    </repository>
                 </repositories>

                 <pluginRepositories>
                    <pluginRepository>
                       <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
                       <name>JBoss Repository</name>
                       <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                       <releases>
                       </releases>
                       <snapshots>
                      <enabled>false</enabled>
                       </snapshots>
                    </pluginRepository>
                 </pluginRepositories>

                 <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests 
                    in a remote JBoss AS instance -->
                 <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-remote -->
                 <id>arq-jbossas-remote</id>
                 <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                       <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                       <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
                       <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                 </dependencies>
                  </profile>

               </profiles>

            </project>
```

Can anyone help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was upgrade from JPA 2.0 to JPA 2.1 module of the Jboss 7.1.1 Final. 
To do this upgrade:

1 - download the JPA 2.1  ---no generic by Hibernate here: [Maven Spec Hibernate JPA 2.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final)

2 - put the jar downloaded here : `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/javax/persistence/api/main` OR If you are using enterprise JBoss (EAP) then put the jar into this folder instead: `JBOSS-EAP-6.4.0\modules\system\layers\base\javax\persistence\api\main` (like lukman commented)

3 - edit the module.xml in the same dir to use that jar downloaded, like these:

```
 <resources>
    <resource-root path="hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
</resources>
```

4 - restart your Jboss

Dont have sure; but it seems the JPA 2.0 doesnt have the javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey() Method. So I was trying to code in JPA 2.1 way; but the Jboss factory uses JPA 2.0 built in instead

Comment: If you are using enterprise JBoss (EAP) then put the jar into this folder instead: `JBOSS-EAP-6.4.0\modules\system\layers\base\javax\persistence\api\main`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using

```
javax.persistence.JoinColumn
```

which is JPA annotation.

This exception occurs of there are conflicting version of `javax.persistence.ForeignKey class`. Check your `classpath` and if you are using `maven` check the dependencies.

If you are using eclipse and maven is integrated with eclipse, then you can get the complete dependency hierarchy of dependencies in `pom.xml`.

There could be multiple versions of the jar having this class, may be through transitive dependency. You might need to exclude the older version.

Comment: My friend, I've checked and re-checked if there's a conflict, but it doesn't. I really cant find where this error came from. I've checked inside the EAR before I deployed this, and the class exists and have this method. I also tried to delete the class javax.persistence.JoinColumn to check (if there's a conflict, it should solve). But nothing. Any other ideia please?

Comment: @xpicanha can you please name the jars or screenshot of your lib folder inside war.