# Application Deployment failing on cloud foundry due to entityManagerFactory bean creation failed

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, openjpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I am facing below error while deploying spring boot microservice on cloud foundry:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/ge/pd/reports/config/HibernateConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
```

As I checked many resolution on stack overflow and many other portals for the solution, All the solution are related to jar version conflicts.

I have eliminated all the conflicts jar from the application and updated with all the jar versions which is required.

```
I am using below jar and its version:
hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar - 5.0.12
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar   - 2.1
hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar - 5.0.12
openjpa-2.4.0.jar - 2.4.0
```

Please Provide the Solution.

Comment: When asking homework type questions, show your best good faith attempt to solve it and tell what problems you are having. This will give us a better understanding of what you're trying to do, what you might be doing wrong, and what you need help with. Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help), the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask), sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

This indeed looks like a dependency conflict, more specifically, between Hibernate 5.0.12 ([which uses JPA 2.1](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.0/)) and OpenJPA 2.4.0 ([which uses JPA 2.0](https://openjpa.apache.org/openjpa-2.4.x.html)). Try removing the OpenJPA dependency.

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588860/error-javax-persistence-joincolumn-foreignkeyljavax-persistence-foreignkey-wi) SO thread shows, the said method was introduced in JPA 2.1.