# I am Unable to locate the application.properties file When I execute

Tags: java, spring

> BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzScheduler'
>   defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not
>   open ServletContext resource [/application.properties]
>                 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]

```
<bean id="quartzScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:configLocation="application.properties"/>
```

Any help please...
config.xml and application.properties are under the src/main/resources

Comment: Take a look to [a duplicate question with accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9179552) and see if it works for your project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not open ServletContext resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035464/could-not-open-servletcontext-resource)